# Autohotkey: detectar Num Lock ativado/desativado

Tags: autohotkey

Usando o Autohotkey, quero mudar a função da tecla *(NumpadMult) do teclado numérico para Tab, mas só quando Num Lock está desativado. Quando Num Lock está ativo, deve permanecer como *. Como é possível?

Answer (score 1):

Pesquisando, acabei achando a resposta à minha própria pergunta:

```
$NumpadMult::
   if ( GetKeyState("NumLock", "T") ) ; this will be 'true' if NumLock is toggled 'on'
      send *   
   Else
      send {tab}
return
```

Fonte:
http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/62251-how-to-make-scroll-lock-toggle-a-hotkey/